# Magento 2 controller not getting url params

Tags: magento2

I have a custom controller that will not get the parameters from the URL. Here is the URL: https://mysite/admin/patpdf/pdf/index/order_id/27490.

It should get the order_id in the `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` or `$this->_request->getParams()`, but nothing shows up. I don't know if I am doing something wrong as everything I have found online says this is how you get URL params, but it's not working for me.

Comment: you should do like this `$this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id')`

Comment: @magefms Tried that too, doesnt work. getParams should show all the parameters in the url, but it's empty.

Comment: how are you passing the data , via post ?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I was trying to get the parameter from inside the constructor. I thought you could do that. It's working properly in my execute function.